# Break the loop into half, if the loop count is even

Tags: php, loops, break

I want to break the loop into half of the total loop count. If the total loop count is odd, I would like to remove the last array item in order to make the total loop count even and add the deleted item to the second half.

Here is the code structure to demonstrate the loop-

```
<?php
$faqs = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => 'faq'
));
?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- The first half of the tootal loop count. -->
      <?php
      while ($faqs->have_posts()) : $faqs->the_post();
          the_content();
      endwhile();
      ?>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- The second half of the tootal loop count. -->
      <?php
      while ($faqs->have_posts()) : $faqs->the_post();
          the_content();
      endwhile();
      ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to control the loop based on my mentioned conditions. That's why I couldn't able to try loop controlling.

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: Where is the array? Where is the attempt?

Comment: Let me update the question with the php loop that I'm trying.

Comment: hi, @ShivCKushawah I have updated the question :)

Answer (score 1):

In a single loop. Hopefully, it'll work. Couldn't test so let me if you face any situation.

```
<?php
$faqs = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
]);
$half = intval($faqs->post_count / 2);
$counter = 0;
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php while ($faqs->have_posts()) : $faqs->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ( $counter === $half ) : ?>
            </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php ++$counter; endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
<?php
$faqs = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => 'faq'
));
?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- The first half of the total loop count. -->
      <?php
      $i=0;
      while ($faqs->have_posts() && $i < $faqs->post_count / 2) : $faqs->the_post(); $i++
          the_content();
      endwhile();
      ?>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- The second half of the tootal loop count. -->
      <?php
      while ($faqs->have_posts()) : $faqs->the_post();
          the_content();
      endwhile();
      ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27116/counting-the-posts-of-a-custom-wordpress-loop-wp-query